# Auto increment ID between classes - JAVA

Tags: java

A hypothetical garage is storing Vehicles (Cars and Bikes).

I am wanting an auto-incrementing id system but I'm not entirely sure how to set it up properly. Please see my code below...

**Vehicle**

```
public class Vehicle {
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    int id;
    double bill;
}
```

**Car (extends Vehicle)**

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
private int noDoors;
public Car(String make, String model, int year, int noDoors) {
    this.id = id++;
    this.noDoors = noDoors;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}
```

}

Comment: Is this homework? Did you actually try anything?

Comment: Use a DB to store the data. If this is just a test program you can probably use singleton. Do take care of what happens when this piece of code is accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: With this shown code, all Vehicles have ID = 1

Comment: @cricket_007 And that is why, as I assume, OP searches for our help :)

Comment: @Zabuza Sure. A database would be the ideal solution, though

Comment: @Oleg This was an exersize I received some time back, just revisiting to pick up skills again. I've seen the solution at some point in the past but it escapes me at silly o'clock at night :P

Comment: @TeaCode A DB would be good but I'm just wanting a simple implementation of a local ID for now

Comment: @larsgrefer It is not homework, just wanting to refresh my skills etc.

Comment: @Zabuza I don't live on here, give me a break!

Comment: Not meant to offend you, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach would be to use a **Factory-Pattern**. A factory is an object that generates instances of objects for you. Then you have one location, where you can manage the **IDs** for all objects.

Alternatively you could use an object where you *register* your objects at. Like an office that hands out **IDs**.

Here is an example using the registration method:

The **registration *office***, using a **singleton-pattern** for making usage more comfortable:

```
public class IdProvider {
    private static IdProvider instance = null;

    public IdProvider getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new IdProvider();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private int nextID = 0;

    public int getUniqueId() {
        if (nextId < 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Out of IDs!");
        }

        int uniqueId = nextId;
        nextId++;

        return uniqueId;
    }
}
```

Your **objects**:

```
public class Vehicle {
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    int id;
    double bill;

    public Vehicle() {
        // Get an ID
        this.id = IdProvider.getInstance().getUniqueId();
    }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private int noDoors;
    public Car(String make, String model, int year, int noDoors) {
        // An ID is fetched implicitly because
        // the super-constructor of Vehicle is
        // always called

        this.noDoors = noDoors;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you are searching for a **quick and dirty** solution, you could use a **static counter** in `Vehicle`:

```
public class Vehicle {
    private static int nextId = 0;

    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    int id;
    double bill;

    public Vehicle() {
        // Get an ID
        this.id = Vehicle.nextId;

        // Increase the ID for the next vehicle
        Vehicle.nextId++;
    }
}
```

A static variable is shared among all instances of a class. So for all vehicles there is only one `nextId` object and they all have access to it.

---

Note that if you plan to use that code in a **parallel environment** (multi-threaded programming) then you must take care with the `getUniqueId` method of `IdProvider`.

You need to `synchronize` it. Or you can also substitute the type of its id counter by `AtomicInteger` which provides thread-safe methods like `AtomicInteger#getAndIncrement` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement--)).

Comment: Thanks for the help @Zabuza. The quick and dirty method was exactly what I was looking for and what I had seen in the past. I had it originally as "this.id = id" with "id++" but that wasn't working at all. Thanks again

Comment: Glad that it helped. It didn't work because you have forgotten the `static` keyword on the variable. Without it every instance of `Vehicle` has its own counter of `id` but you only want *one global counter*. This can be reached with `static`, it uncouples a variable from instances and lifts it to the namespace of the class itself (*static-context*).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a sequence of identifiers that are unique within the lifetime of the JVM, you could use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) counter in the super class. The counter would be incremented by the super class constructor as follows:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

    protected int id;
    protected String make;
    protected String model;
    protected int year;

    private static AtomicInteger idSequence = new AtomicInteger();

    protected Vehicle(String make, String model, int year) {
        this.id = idSequence.incrementAndGet();
        // set the super class fields
    }
}
```

Then, in the subclasses you would call the super class constructor, before setting subclass-specific fields:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private int noDoors;

    public Car(String make, String model, int year, int noDoors) {
        super(make, model, year);
        // set the sub-class fields
    }
 }
```